# ASP.NET MVC3: Private resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, resources, private

Is there any way to make resources private.

I have a video content site. They upload. Files get stored on the web-server.

Files get embedded back onto the site.

Now if I view the "source code" in google chrome, I see :

```
<object classid="clsid:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6" height="400" width="600" >
<param name="URL" value="/Videos/Tree%20Felling.wmv" />
<param name="autoStart" value="False" />
<param name="uiMode" value="full" />
<param name="stretchToFit" value="True" />
<param name="volume" value="75" />
<embed src="/Videos/Tree%20Felling.wmv" width="600" height="400" type="application/x-mplayer2" autoStart="False" uiMode="full" stretchToFit="True" volume="75" />
</object>
```

As you can see, **the location is now made known.** Append this to the site address, and hey presto you can access the video directly? Meaning you can save the file or access it from other location where login is not achieved.

**Whats to stop them using the URL and embedding it into their website etc.**

Or am I thinking wrongly?

How do I prevent such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Following this, I found on another question.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx)

The solution is to add a web.config to the folder you wish to deny access to.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*"/>
            <deny users="?" />              
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This means they must be logged into your website to be granted access to the media. And hence, cant leech videos/content.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem. My solution would be to create a custom HttpHandler ([msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx)) and assign it to some custom extension, ***.zzz,** so when you generate the src for the embed element it would look like this: /Videos/uploaded.zzz?id={someId}. Then in the HttpHandler I would resolve id to the video being requested and return in response. If you worried about someone direct linking to the /Videos/uploaded.zzz url you can have the handler code (**ProcessRequest** method) check if user is authorized (logged in during request) before returning the media file. You can get as fancy as you want, adding throttling based on the number of requests to the file, etc.

I have not written the code to test this, but it should be pretty trivial.

Comment: This wouldnt stop them from using their own embedding to direct link the URL. They can by pass any security you so mention. What is necessary would be to make the videos only visible to my website. So no one can direct link.